# Vue js text highlight filter

Tags: javascript, text, formatting, vue.js

I need help writing a text highlight filter using vuejs. The idea is to loop through a given array of words and if there is a match, apply a span with a class to that word. The problem I have is that, I can't seem to return data with html formatting with vuejs. Any ideas will be highly appreciated. I am really stuck with this.

```
Vue.filter('highlight', function(words, query){
    //loop through **words** and if there is a match in **query**
   //apply a <span> with some style
   //At the end return formatted string to html page
})
```

Comment: https://markjs.io/

Answer (score 18):

**HTML interpolations {{{ foo }}} have been removed in favor of the v-html directive in vuejs2.X**, thus from version 2.x, Vue.js allows for raw JavaScript templating (React-style) in addition to HTML templating.
@jeff's answer is correct but for vuejs 1.x versions, but in case {{{}}} didn't work for you guys or if you want to evaluate the tags in the HTML, and from a trusted source, example, if you want to add a `<strong></strong>` tag, then you need to use v-html, the v-html to ask Vue to evaluate the string as HTML:

```
<span v-html="$options.filters.highlight(item, val)">{{ item }}</span>
```

highlight filter:

```
Vue.filter('highlight', function(word, query){
  var check = new RegExp(query, "ig");
  return word.toString().replace(check, function(matchedText,a,b){
      return ('<strong>' + matchedText + '</strong>');
  });
});
```

or you can use @Thomas Ferro's filter

Comment: A slightly different version that let you use multiple queries (comma separated): ```/**
 * 
 * @param { String } words 
 * @param { String } query 
 */
export const highlight = (words, query) => {
    var check = new RegExp(query.split(",").join("|"), "ig");

    return words.toString().replace(
        check,
        (matchedText, a, b) => {
            return `<strong>${matchedText}</strong>`
        }
    )
}```

Comment: good sample, thanks I used this. It would be nice if you can add a warning of the potential security risk when using v-html

Answer (score 13):

As Jeff just said, the basic mustaches interprets the data as plain text.

You can add your span by replacing the query with the [String.replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method.

Here's a basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/0jew7LLz/

```
Vue.filter('highlight', function(words, query) {
    return words.replace(query, '<span class="highlight">' + query + '</span>')
});
```

Comment: This is risky to use if words is not sanitized.

Comment: is it possible when I call vue version 2?

Comment: I don't know if you can declare global filters, like in the example, but the scoped filters are still available : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Comment: string.replace will replace one segment only. Regex may be necessary to highlight all match text.

Answer (score 5):

The idea is to use split and keep the words that the regex matches.

Here is a user safe component that escapes html and highlights a regexp that searches for multiple words:

```
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['msg', 'search', 'effect'],
  template: '<span><span v-for="(s, i) in parsedMsg" v-bind:class="getClass(i%2)">{{s}}</span></span>',
  methods: {
    getClass: function(i) {
      var myClass = {};
      myClass[this.effect] = !!i;
      return myClass;
    },
  },
  computed: {
    parsedSearch : function () {
        return '(' + this.search.trim().replace(/ +/g, '|') + ')';
    },
    parsedMsg: function() {
        return this.msg.split(
        new RegExp(this.parsedSearch , 'gi'));
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  }
  // ...
})
```

Usage example:

```
<div id="app">
  <child msg="My life so good and awesome, is'nt it great?" search="   life   is   good  " effect='highlight'> </child>
</div>
```

jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/50xvqatm/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `{{{ foo | highlight }}}` with 3 braces, not with 2 `{{}}`.  Two braces escapes HTML.

Comment: I didn't know this was possible.. learned something new.. appreciated.

Comment: Hi, but what if you still want to escape the string, just not the highlight?

Comment: Cette réponse n'est pas valide chez moi en version 2.X.